# where to find the location of an installed package?

Tags: opencl

I ran the following and have no idea where it got installed

```
sudo apt-get install opencl-headers
```

I thought it went here: /usr/include

but it might have gone here: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
I tried both like on the following

```
-DOPENCL_INCLUDE_DIRS=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

I am getting duplicate definition such as
time_t and time64_t so it appears that neither of the above are the actual include for opencl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's take a look at the package description:

> $ apt show opencl-headers
>
> ...  This metapackage depends on packages providing the C and C++
> headers files  for the OpenCL API as published by The Khronos Group
> Inc.  The corresponding  specification and documentation can be found
> on the Khronos website.  ...

A *metapackage* doesn't provide ANY files itself. Instead, dependencies provide the files. We must look up the dependencies of this metapackage:

```
$ apt depends opencl-headers

opencl-headers
  Depends: opencl-c-headers (= 2.2~2019.01.17-g49f07d3-1)
  Depends: opencl-clhpp-headers (>= 2.0.10)
```

So you must look at *those* packages for the files provided.

After you know which package(s) to look at, dpkg has a convenient feature to list the files provided any installed package.

From `man dpkg`:

```
      -L, --listfiles package-name...
          List files installed to your system from package-name.
```

For example, here are the files installed by the `hello` package:

```
$ dpkg -L hello

/.
/usr
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/hello
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/hello
/usr/share/doc/hello/NEWS.gz
/usr/share/doc/hello/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/hello/copyright
/usr/share/info
/usr/share/info/hello.info.gz
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/share/man/man1/hello.1.gz
```

For fun, let's also work backwards and determine whoch package provides a specific file:

```
      -S, --search filename-search-pattern...
          Search for a filename from installed packages.
```

In this example, you can see that the file is provided by the `hello` package:

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/share/doc/hello/NEWS.gz

hello: /usr/share/doc/hello/NEWS.gz
```

Comment: Thanks, found it but also found another problem and was able to solve it.  I found the opencl folder at /usr/include/CL  but another problem arose.  The source file was "CL/cl.h" and the cmake had to be /usr/include  to get the CL  BUT BUT that include picked up all types of conflicts with mingw.  So I created the folder "OpenCL" and moved the "CL" folder into it.  That allowed me to change the cmake to "/usr/include/OpenCL" which got the CL folder but did not cause conflicting definitions such as time64_t and time_t as well as 100's of others.